# Bundle behaviour differs inside ios simulator and actual device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, bundle

At the moment I'm trying to manage a large number of images by putting them in a folder and naming the folder [something].bundle, and dragging these into XCode.

Weird thing right now is that, if I run this in the simulator, I can get access to these images with [UIImage imageNamed:] as if all the files are within the main bundle; but running the same code on a actual device (iPad 4.3.3 in this case), imageNamed: doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me why this might be?

Comment: Device is case-sensitive. Ensure that the names match..

Comment: I should add, this code was modified from existing working code, so all the names watched. The only difference was the use of .bundle folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use imageNamed: with items in a bundle.

You need to either to imageWithContentsOfFile: or imageWithData:

See [(iPhone) Use external image in UIImage imageNamed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754551/iphone-use-external-image-in-uiimage-imagenamed) for similar examples.